# How does a router know an IP address's network prefix when it comes to CIDR?

Tags: router, ip, ip-address

Let's say I start a new company and lease a block of IP address `222.123.123.0/25` from Internet registry, so one of those IP address `222.123.123.4` is my main web server.

A customer from a different country wants to send a packet to this IP address, how does the the router (an ISP's router at his country) know what is the network prefix of this IP address `222.123.123.4`? Because classful IP addressing is deprecated, when it comes to CIDR IP addresses, it can be `222.123.123.4/25`, `222.123.123.4/26`, `222.123.123.4/27` etc., and IP header certainly doesn't have a header called `network prefix`.

So how does the router determine the network prefix of an IP address?

Comment: why would an ISP router need the network prefix?

Comment: @JaromandaX then how does the ISP router know what is the network prefix of an ip address? or if ISP router has a routing table that contain the rules that how to route ip address with network prefix, then how does this rule (contain network prefix) populated from local Router up the way up to a different country's ISP router?

Comment: BGP is complex. And you may be right, your `222.123.123.0/25` may well be one of the countless routes in the BGP tables somewhere

Comment: @JaromandaX thanks for your answer, and so when 222.123.123.0/25 is assigned to me, do I need to manually enter the network prefix "/25" info into the my localrouter? or my local  router can somehow query Internet registry and get that "oh, `222.123.123.4` 's network prefix is /25

Comment: I wasn't saying that - you were talking about how does some other ISP know how to route to your address. I dare say you would specify the prefix somewhere on your router, and/or on your devices so they would "know" that 222.123.123.0/25 is a local subnet, but again, that wasn't what you were asking.

Comment: @JaromandaX so if I ask a different question now,   after  `222.123.123.0/25` is assigned to me, how does local router know an ip address in that range has /25 network prefix?

Comment: you configure it to be so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Your** router knows the prefix length because you configure it. Whenever an interface is configured with an address, whether on a host or on a router, the prefix length (or the equivalent netmask) is entered alongside it.

It's functionally the same as IPv4 configuration for your Windows PC at home – the PC knows it's 192.168.1.x/24 because it has "Netmask: 255.255.255.0" filled in; the router knows it's .123.1/25 because you (or the ISP) had to specify the "/25" when doing `ip addr add`.

**Distant** routers either a) do not care or b) will learn a route towards your /25 as you advertise it via BGP to your upstream ISPs, and the **same BGP advertisement** includes the route prefix length together with the network address. All routing protocols in use today have been extended to carry the prefix length – that's the whole point of the "CIDR" effort.

Note however that distant routers only care about the *route* prefix, at most. They do not care about your *subnet* size – the BGP advertisement may cover multiple of your subnets (an aggregate route), or it may cover half a subnet, none of it makes any difference for the packet delivery.

Things like "reserved for broadcast" addresses do not enter into play here, so packets to ".0" and ".255" addresses will just be forwarded without any special treatment (the destination might not even be a broadcast-capable subnet at all; it might be a /31 or /32 PtP link where any address is valid).

(The decoupling of routes and subnets happened even before CIDR – it's literally why the "subnet mask" is called a *sub*-net mask; it used to be that BGP continued carrying only classful routes for quite a while even as the operators already had their classful networks internally subdivided into classless subnets.)

This means a host or a basic CPE router can just have a single 0.0.0.0/0 route (the "default" route) and will absolutely not care about whether some distant network is /25 or something else.

In most cases, ISPs will *only* advertise aggregate routes via BGP and not individual subnet routes – it's generally frowned upon to do otherwise, as the global BGP tables are already large. (In fact, you're not even allowed to advertise an IPv4 /25 on the public Internet; ISPs only accept advertisements for /24 or larger, or similarly /48 for IPv6.)

In other words, there's no "Network prefix" field in IP headers because the *only* device that needs to know it – the final router at your site – already has that information configured explicitly.